# Transferring Apple dev account & certificate to new machine

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, provisioning-profile, in-house-distribution

I've recently attempted to transfer my apple dev certificate to a new mac, however, the provisioning profiles are appearing as valid signing identity not found.

I imported my developer account into Xcode5 and when I deploy a build, I get the option to fix the issue of not having a valid signing - this generates an iOS team provisioning profile for the bundle id.

So far have found this is fine for testing - we distribute ourselves not using the app store.

If anyone would be able to give me a heads up on whether this is an okay method, or whether I will need to generate a new certificate for distribution in case we do use the app store for distribution.

Comment: Doesn't just using `Preferences > Accounts` in Xcode 5 do everything without the need to export/import anything?

Comment: That's what I thought - but provisioning profiles are showing as invalid & Xcode generates a team provisioning profile with the same bundle id - everything still works fine... just don't want any nasty surprises ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you need to do is to remake the developer and distribution certificates for your new mac and install it then, you update your provision profile with the new certificate, reinstall it and everything works

PS: for remake your developer and distribution certificates you have to go in the keychan 
Certificate Assistant > Request a Certificate From a Certificate Authority..
then add your email and common Name, check Saved to disk. Finally Into the developer web site you remove your old certificates and create the new one with the new file that you have in the disk.

Comment: Ah thank you very much sir - I no longer have access to the old mac, so will have to remake a certificate.

Answer (score 6):

If you still have access to your previous computer, you can export as p12 the private key you used to generate the Apple certificate.

Go to keychain, select the iOS certificate and right click to export it. Then import it to your new computer and you do not need to generate new certificates.

Comment: I have a mac from which i created a development certificate and provisional certificate for development, so now i have another mac i don't want to create new certificates to another mac. So what i did i have downloaded certificate from developers account to previous mac from which it has been created and  exported through key chain excess to desktop with extension .p12 what will i do further @slecorne

Answer (score 0):

Did you export from Xcode → Preferences → Accounts like Apple's [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-accounts_preferences/articles/export_signing_assets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013306-CH8-SW1) suggests?
Did you also export your private key from the keychain? I have seen this issue before, and that was resolved by exporting and importing the private key.

If you do want to distribute on App Store later on you will definitely need to import a valid certificate, yes.

Answer (score -3):

here you can find a solution or ask your problem to a developers Apple support:

https://developer.apple.com/support/

Other way you can call the developer support center here:

https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php